# my <ul> dissapears when generating <li> in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm having a weird error where my UL tag dissapears when I generate LI tags in it, I have no idea what it could be so if anyone here could help me that would be great.

The HTML it gets generated in:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="tickets">
        <ul>'.$Ticket->generateTickets().'</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My PHP function

```
public function generateTickets(){
    $cols = Array ('ID','description','ticket_id');
    $items = $this->db->orderBy('ID')->get("tickets", null, $cols);
    if ($this->db->count > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item) { 
            echo '<li><a href="?p=support&action=readticket&tid='.$item['ID'].'">Ticket #'.$item['ticket_id'].'<br/></a>
            <p>'.substr($item['description'],0,20).'..</p>
            </li>';
        }
    }
}
```

console showing that the ul just dissapeared:
http://piclair.com/r45q7

Comment: Console output can be decisive sometimes. Please check the source code, just to be sure if it's really disappearing.

Comment: Don't compare the PHP to the DOM viewer. Look at the HTML source code generated by the PHP. Also run it through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your generateTickets function, you're echoing immediately. Since the concatenation in your html file is done after the function is done, they get output first. You should either return the values ( replace `echo` with `return` and move it out of the loop ) or in html, dont concatenate strings.

```
$result = '';
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $result .= '<li ...';
}
return $result;
```